# Forcing app to launch Safari

Tags: iphone

I used the code below to launch safari when user taps an URL link of a web page display on web view:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]])
            return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

It works both on iOS 4 and iOS 5.

However, on iOS4, it launched safari, but when I closed the browser and went back to app, web view was continuing to go to the url I'd sent to safari.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Try after removing ! from if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]]), it may help

Comment: mithilesh please reply as answer, I will accept yours

Comment: you can up vote to comments also. 1 or 2 line answer is display as comment.

Comment: @priyanka however they don't boost reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    { 
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]])
            return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing ! from if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]]), as below-

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
        {
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]])
                return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

It may help you ....